# TinyMCE 4 Container not floating under label, but covers label?

Tags: css-float, label, textarea, css-position, tinymce-4

I'm using TinyMCE for my CMS and i have a form with a couple of labels and inputs. All my inputs and textareas are floating under the label with by the following CSS:

```
label {
float: left;
clear: left;
}

input, textarea {
float: left;
clear: left;
}
```

But when i use TinyMCE to override the textareas, the TinyMCE container is overlapping the label instead of floating under the label. How come and how can i fix this? I would rather not make use of position absolute and relative, because all of my elements are positioned with the float property.

Greetings,

Jan

Answer (score 0):

TinyMCE only renders within text areas by default and HTML labels only appear outside so what you're saying doesn't seem possible. Please provide the HTML and possibly a Fiddle so we can see what's going on.

As a blind suggestion try adding bottom margin or padding to your label element. If that doesn't work try giving it a large height.